# shortestPath relationship does not reflect the correct direction

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Neo4j and is developing a small site.

I have setup the nodes and relationships between them. For most of the paired nodes, I created a mutual link. For example:

```
Zeus - FATHER -> Apollo
Appollo - SON -> Zeus
```

I used `shortestPath` to find the possible shortest path between these two:

```
MATCH (o1 { name: 'Apollo' }),(o2 { name: 'Zeus' }), p = shortestPath((o1)-[*..6]-(o2)) RETURN nodes(p), relationships(p)
```

The result is that it returns "FATHER" instead of "SON".

If I change the query to `[*..6]->(o2)`, "SON" is returned.

But I need to consider the search may make `o1` a node with no outgoing relationship, in which case, the above-modified query fails.

So:

1. The original query can cope with nodes with no outgoing relationship, but may return wrong relationship.
2. The modified query can return right relationship (so far) but can't cope with "no out relation" nodes.

I can of course change every node to have at least one outgoing relation to fix Issue 2 but that will be too redundant.

Hope to get your advice.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad practice to create bidirectional relationships like you do, specially when it's a bijection.

You are duplicating some data in the database (it's obvious that if `Zeus` is the father of `Apollo`, `Apollo` is the son of `Zeus`).

This query :

```
MATCH 
  (o1 { name: 'Apollo' }),
  (o2 { name: 'Zeus' }), 
  p = shortestPath((o1)-[*..6]-(o2)) 
RETURN nodes(p), relationships(p)
```

search only **one** shortestpath. But due to the duplication, there is in fact **two** shortestpaths. You can replace the `shortestpath` function by  the `allshortestpaths` to find all. So youwill have the `son` and `father` result.

Or you can also give to the shortestpath function, a list of relationship type thath it can traverse like this:

```
MATCH 
  (o1 { name: 'Apollo' }),
  (o2 { name: 'Zeus' }), 
  p = shortestPath((o1)-[:FATHER*..6]-(o2)) 
RETURN nodes(p), relationships(p)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I did not agree with your point because if A is FATHER of B, B could be A's SON or DAUGHTER. Or, if A is SON of B, B could be A's FATHER or MOTHER. This kind of relationship is only one directional, and you can't induce what is the reciprocal relationship type.

Comment: You can have a rel type `PARENT_OF`, and on each node you can specify the sexe.

Comment: By doing this, we are compromising Neo4j. Instead of a quick and straight search on "link" - which is what Neo4j is best at, we have to search an additional property. I don't think that is a good idea.

Comment: it depends of your needs. In your case, when you need to create or delete a `FATHER` link, you have to also create/delete the `SON` or `DAUGHTER` relationship. So it will be faster for reads (in some case), but slower on writes, and you have to maintain the data consistency by yourself.